# Como setar Nothing pra uma variável do tipo DateTime?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

Tenho uma função que recebe uma *string* e é convertida pra date time, fiz uma verificação pra quando vier *string* vazio, retornar `Nothing`. Mas quando sai da função está me retornando a data nesse formato `#12:00:00 AM#`, o que eu quero é que venha apenas `Nothing` ou algo do tipo.

Aqui está minha variável que recebe o retorno:

```
Dim data as DateTime? = RetornaDataFormatada(strValor)
```

E aqui minha função reduzida:

```
Public Function RetornaDataFormatada(ByVal strValor As String) As DateTime

        If strValor = "" Then

            Return Nothing

        End If

        Return Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para `DateTime` não é possível, este é um tipo por valor que não aceita valores nulos. Porém é possível retornar `Nothing` para um tipo `DateTime?`. Me parece que não teria problema para você já que vai usar em uma variável deste tipo.

Note que a interrogação faz toda diferença, com e sem são tipos diferentes, com semânticas diferentes.

Desta forma basta mudar o tipo de retorna, assim:

```
Public Function RetornaDataFormatada(ByVal strValor As String) As DateTime?
    If strValor = "" Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/NullableDateTime.vb).

Evidentemente esta função não faz nada útil a não ser retornar `Noting` em todas situações. Isto não é importante para o problema da perguntas mas fica a dica se você não percebeu.

Comment: Cara, eu pensei nisso, até cheguei a fazer, o problema é que usa em vários lugares ai da erro de conversão explicita!
 você acha que esse é o melhor caminho, e eu altere os locais de chamada dessa função?

Comment: É o único caminho para o que você quer. O erro que você está obtendo obviamente é normal, você teria que fazer adaptações em em todos esses ligares para tratar de forma apropriada. Se tem lugares que estão esperando um `DateTime`, não pode receber um `DateTime?` impunemente, porque no segundo pode ter um valor inválido no primeiro. Então você só pode fazer a conversão explicitamente. O que não sei se deve. Pelo menos não deve sem salvaguardar condicionalmente.

Comment: Ok, vou seguir suas orientações, obrigado!